# Diagnose : Maximum+number+of+open+connections+reached

Tags: windows-7, 64-bit, kaspersky

I am facing a strange problem on my PC running Win 7 Pro 64 bits
I experience a lot of "Maximum number of open connections reached" while browsing
I am using Google Chrome 37.0.2062.103 (Build officiel 291558) m
I was using the 64bit version

I seems to me that it has started after upgrading from 36 to 37

I refresh one page of chrome, I have now 190 connections like that

TCP    127.0.0.1:11282        127.0.0.1:1111         TIME_WAIT       0

Last column is 0 as process Id

With chrome opened , idle I have a few active connections (2184 is the pid of chrome)

TCP    127.0.0.1:1049         127.0.0.1:65001        ESTABLISHED     3784
  TCP    127.0.0.1:1110         127.0.0.1:8680         ESTABLISHED     2184
  TCP    127.0.0.1:1110         127.0.0.1:8686         ESTABLISHED     2184
  TCP    127.0.0.1:1110         127.0.0.1:9444         ESTABLISHED     2184
  TCP    127.0.0.1:1110         127.0.0.1:10592        ESTABLISHED     2184
  TCP    127.0.0.1:1110         127.0.0.1:11041        TIME_WAIT       0
  TCP    127.0.0.1:1544         127.0.0.1:65000        ESTABLISHED     5908
  TCP    127.0.0.1:8680         127.0.0.1:1110         ESTABLISHED     6856
  TCP    127.0.0.1:8686         127.0.0.1:1110         ESTABLISHED     6856
  TCP    127.0.0.1:9444         127.0.0.1:1110         ESTABLISHED     6856
  TCP    127.0.0.1:10592        127.0.0.1:1110         ESTABLISHED     6856
  TCP    127.0.0.1:11030        127.0.0.1:1111         TIME_WAIT       0
  TCP    127.0.0.1:65000        127.0.0.1:1544         ESTABLISHED     3784
  TCP    127.0.0.1:65001        127.0.0.1:1049         ESTABLISHED     3784
  TCP    192.168.192.158:1539   192.168.192.4:445      CLOSE_WAIT      4
  TCP    192.168.192.158:1589   157.56.124.114:443     TIME_WAIT       0
  TCP    192.168.192.158:8681   74.125.24.188:5228     ESTABLISHED     2184
  TCP    192.168.192.158:8687   173.194.40.73:443      ESTABLISHED     2184
  TCP    192.168.192.158:9445   74.125.24.102:443      ESTABLISHED     2184
  TCP    192.168.192.158:10593  95.100.210.110:443     ESTABLISHED     2184
  TCP    192.168.192.158:11028  81.19.104.69:443       TIME_WAIT       0
  TCP    192.168.192.158:11037  134.170.109.72:443     TIME_WAIT       0
  TCP    192.168.192.158:11038  134.170.109.72:443     TIME_WAIT       0

This test was done in incognito mode (so no extension) and my antivirus Kaskersky 15 disabled

Comment: Is 192.168.192.158 a device you have on your network?  These connections are internal so possibly a printer or other device.

Comment: Yes 192.168.192.158 is my own PC

Comment: Open connections are common.  Use a lookup tool to see what the IPs are.  Many are likely related to browsing or a local app like AV or other software that checks for updates(Adobe,Java, Flash and the like).  If the IP addresses are not easily identified, you will need to dig further.  I would not immediately assume malware

Answer (score -1):

It's malware.   I caught mine with "Malwarebytes Anti-Malware", once the software quarantined an number of files, my web browser functioned normally again.   All those connections are siphoning off your data and files.